# Append div element when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a `<div>` element to my container when the current window scroll height is below or above the current page the user is scrolled to. In the markup below:

```
<div id="st-container" class="st-container">
      <div class=" fullscreen-container animated fadeInDown" id="fullscreen-container">
            <div class=" custom_inner offset2" id="fullscreen">
              <div class="pageHolder" id="3">
               </div>
               <div class="pageHolder" id="4">
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The `<div>` elements i am working with have the class `pageHolder`, in a `$(window).scroll()` function, i would like to get the height of the current page holder and append on top or bottom, depending on how the user is scrolling, a new div element if the element doesn't exist, the element doesn't exist if I can't find it by the `id`. I have tried this so far but unsure where to go from:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
     $('.pageHolder').each(function(){
         var position = $(this).position();
     })
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is exactly what your looking to do as I'm a bit confused with your explanation but I thought I give it a shot :D

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('.pageHolder').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            position = $this.position(),
            id = parseInt($this.attr('id')),
            $div = $('<div>');

        if(scrollTop  > position.top){
            /*
             If window scrollTop is greater that its top position
             check if the immediate succeeding sibling exist 
            */
            if(!$this.next('.pageHolder').length){
                /*
                 If its next sibling does not exist
                 create a new sibling <div> by inserting it after this 'pageHolder'
                */
                $div.addClass('pageHolder').attr('id',id+1).text('pageHolder id'+(id+1));
                $this.after($div)
            }          
        }else{ 
            if(!$this.prev('.pageHolder').length){
                $div.addClass('pageHolder').attr('id',id-1).text('pageHolder id'+(id-1));
                $this.before($div)
            }
        }
    });

    /*
    Make a continouos scroll when scrolling up
    Without this set of code, prepending a new <div> is not possible
    */
    if(scrollTop == 0){
        $(window).scrollTop(50);
    }

}).scrollTop(50); //Make the window start with a scrollTop of 50, this is essential for the continouos scrolling up
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/syJt7/).